# Existence en regularity of elliptic PDE with mixed boundary

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Let $\Omega=\mathbb{D}\cap\{ (x,y)\, \vert\, y>0\}$, $I=(-1,1)\times \{0\}$ and $A=\partial\Omega\setminus I$. Let $Q\in L^1(\Omega)$, and $R\in C^\infty_{loc}(I)$.

I am looking to the following problem

$$
 \left\{
      \begin{aligned}
        \Delta \psi = Q  & \hbox{ in }  \Omega \\
        \psi = 0 & \hbox{ on } A \\
        \partial_{\nu}\psi = R  & \hbox{ on } I \\
      \end{aligned}
    \right.
$$

What is the best regularity I can expect on $\psi$? is it at least continuous? This case doesn't seem so classical, I found nothing precise in Gilbarg & Trudinger for instance, and perhaps the fact my domain get corners could be problematic.... any precise reference would be welcome.

Thanks in advance

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

If Needed, but the main assumption are above:

I know a bit more on $Q$ and $R$, for instance I have
$$ \vert Q(z)\vert \leq \frac{C}{(1-\vert z\vert)^2}$$
and
$$ \vert R(z)\vert \leq \frac{C}{(1-\vert z\vert)}$$

but of cours no $L^\infty$ bound.

Comment: If I remember correctly such problems with mixed Dirichlet-Neumann conditions are discussed in in the book P. Grisvard, Elliptic Problems in Nonsmooth Domains.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is nothing about this kind of condition, it is more about linear combination of Dirichlet and Neumann

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The continuity of $\psi$ up to $\partial \Omega$ is false without more control on $R$.

Consider for example the harmonic function that is $1$ on the upper half-circle and $-1$ on the lower half-circle. A model for the behavior near e.g. the lower left corner is the (zero-homogeneous) angle function $\frac{2}{\pi} \Im\, \log(z + 1)$, which on $I$ has normal derivative blowing up like inverse of distance to the corner. One can compute the exact solution using complex analysis:
$$\psi = \frac{2}{\pi}\Im\,\log\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right) = \frac{2}{\pi}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2y}{1-|z|^2}\right),$$
which satisfies
$$Q=  0, \quad R = \psi_y(x,\,0) = \frac{4}{\pi(1-x^2)} \leq \frac{C}{1-|x|}.$$

Comment: It looks a good counter example for continuity. Can we expect boundeness?